# Spring boot Security Disable security

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

When I use **security.basic.enabled=false** to disable security on a Spring Boot project that has the following dependencies:

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I see the following **Exception:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration$ManagementWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

In order to fix this exception I had to add the property - **management.security.enabled=false** . My understanding is that when the actuator is in the classpath, both **security.basic.enabled=false** and **management.security.enabled=false** should be set to disable the security.

Could someone please let me know if my understanding is wrong?

Comment: Why do you need security on your classpath if you just want to disable everything? Anyway, your stack trace is incomplete so there is no way to know what was preventing the app from starting. I would expect it would start, but the actuator endpoints should stay secure until you explicitly open them up.

Comment: @DaveSyer I would like to disable security temporarily and also my application code refers security jars to work.

Comment: You still haven't posted enough information to see why the app isn't starting. A full stack trace would be a start.

Comment: @DaveSyer One reason would be a microservice managing spring-sec-oauth2 `ClientDetails`. You'll have a transitive import of spring-security but maybe don't want basic auth in your service.

Answer (score 123):

In case you have spring-boot-actuator in your package, you should add the following

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

With older Spring-boot, the class was called `ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration`.

In newer versions this has changed to

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
        org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class}
        )
```

**UPDATE**

If for reactive application you are having the same issue, you can exclude the following classes

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Comment: Two more auto configurations that need to be excluded as well:
SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityRequestMatcherProviderAutoConfiguration.class

Comment: Thanks for the new version one. I have lost an hour until I found your answer :)

Comment: What does excluding ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration do? Excluding SecurityAutoConfiguration seems to have removed login prompts from my app, which is all I wanted. I'm using Spring Boot 3.

Comment: It is to not autoconfigure the login page. Spring works with wise default.... so if you do not configure anything, it just picks up the default setup it assumes that you would need. This is just to say do nothing and then you are free to configure what you want.

Answer (score 87):

What also seems to work fine is creating a file `application-dev.properties` that contains:

```
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
```

If you then start your Spring Boot app with the `dev` profile, you don't need to log on.

Comment: security.basic.enabled=false is not needed if you disable security with management.security.enabled=false

Comment: I also added `security.ignored=/**` then worked.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36280413/3291867

Comment: This is now deprecated!

Comment: Indeed. See https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/security-changes-in-spring-boot-2-0-m4 for more info on the deprecation that happened in Spring Boot 2

Answer (score 63):

For **Spring Boot 2** following properties are deprecated in **application.yml** configuration

```
  security.basic.enabled: false
  management.security.enabled: false
```

To disable security for **Sprint Boot 2 Basic + Actuator Security** following properties can be used in **application.yml** file instead of annotation based exclusion
*(@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class}))*

```
  spring:
    autoconfigure:
      exclude[0]: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
      exclude[1]: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
```

For **application.properties** syntax would be like

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude[0]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: Thanks! I temporarily applied this with an environment variable to a springboot 2+ app in a docker container using: `SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"spring":{"autoconfigure":{"exclude[0]":"org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration","exclude[1]":"org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration"}}}'`

Comment: Two more auto configurations that need to be excluded as well: SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityRequestMatcherProviderAutoConfiguration.class

Comment: @dlamblin I tried your snippet but I got: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse JSON` Any ideas why?

Comment: Still getting authorization error? What could be the reason?

Answer (score 43):

If you need security as a dependency but don't want Spring Boot to configure it for you, you can use this exclusion:

```
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { 
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class 
    })
```

Comment: Two more auto configurations that need to be excluded as well: SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityRequestMatcherProviderAutoConfiguration.class

Answer (score 29):

For the spring boot 2 users it has to be

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Comment: What happened to ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration in spring boot 2.0

Comment: You might still have to comment your `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation

Comment: Two more auto configurations that need to be excluded as well: SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityRequestMatcherProviderAutoConfiguration.class

Comment: @EugeneMaysyuk "SecurityRequestMatcherProviderAutoConfiguration" <- I am not finding this!

Comment: @SGuru let me take a look

Comment: @SGuru What Spring Boot version are you using? It is possible that those classes have different names. It depends on Spring Boot version.

Answer (score 13):

Step 1: Comment annotation @EnableWebSecurity in your security config

```
//@EnableWebSecurity
```

Step 2: Add this to your **application.properties** file.

```
security.ignored=/**
spring.security.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
security.basic.enabled=false
```

For more details look here: http://codelocation.com/how-to-turn-on-and-off-spring-security-in-spring-boot-application/

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work. Once I start spring-boot, it will create the default security filter chain: 2020-11-29 18:48:58.095  INFO 30744 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7c9e4dd, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1d14d528, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3fc159ad, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@71b72226, org.springframework.security....

Comment: This worked for me I'm using Spring Boot 1.7.4. I didn't need to comment `@EnableWebSecurity`.

Answer (score 11):

Add following class into your code

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

/**
 * @author vaquar khan
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    }

}
```

And insie of application.properties add

```
security.ignored=/**
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
```

Answer (score 8):

Answer is to allow all requests in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter as below.

you can do this in existing class or in new class.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
```

Please note : If ther is existing GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration class, you must disable it.

Comment: Not worked. But this one worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security#answer-58858524

Comment: Hi ravi, as per your solution, it is not recommended to disable csrf in production as "http.csrf.disable()". did you get CSRF issue for POST,etc calls?

Comment: @U_R_NaveenUR_Naveen I wrote the same code snippet but it didn't work. The login page still appears when I run the spring boot app. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `@WebMvcTest` annotation in your test class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration"})
```

doesn't help you.

You can disable security here

```
@WebMvcTest(secure = false)
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way for Spring Boot 2 without dependencies or code changes is just:

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: This is not working with Spring Boot v2.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: would be helpful if you say where to put this code...

Comment: This works in springboot version 2.7.5. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Permit access to everything using antMatchers("/")

```
     protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("configure");
                    http.csrf().disable();
                    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
        }
```

Comment: Problem with this is, access and security are not the same thing. You might be able to permit access to everything, but that does not set security off. For example, malicious looking strings still are catched.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing that worked for me:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
```

and

```
security.ignored=/**
```

Could be that the properties part is redundant or can be done in code, but had no time to experiment. Anyway is temporary.

Answer (score 4):

With Spring Boot 3, the configuration syntax has changed. The following did the trick for me -

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

    @Configuration
    public class SecurityConfig {
    
        @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
            return http.build();
        }
    }
```

More details in my blog post [Spring Boot 3 + Security - Disable Authentication](https://www.javainuse.com/boot3/sec/2)

Answer (score 3):

I simply added `security.ignored=/**`in the `application.properties`,and that did the charm.

Comment: so that means automatic security mechanism is still in place but is just ignoring the all paths. I wouldn't be comfortable in keeping the things that are not required

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid security you can use annotations.
Use this annotation on top of configure class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
```

For example:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class AuthFilter{
   // configured method 
}
```

Comment: Why should `@EnableWebSecurity` disable Web Security?

Comment: At least, it disables the default security configuration in Spring Boot

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this entry to **application.properties** to bypass *Springboot Default Security*

`spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration`

Then there won't be any authentication box.
otrws, credentials are:-
`user` and `99b962fa-1848-4201-ae67-580bdeae87e9` *(password randomly generated)*

`Note: my springBootVersion = '1.5.14.RELEASE'`

Comment: without this,security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false
security.ignored=/** is not enough is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

You can **configure to toggle spring security** in your project by following below 2 steps:

**STEP 1:**
  Add a `@ConditionalOnProperty` annotation on top of your SecurityConfig class. Refer below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity (prePostEnabled = true)
@ConditionalOnProperty (name = "myproject.security.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
   // your security config
}
```

**STEP 2:**
Add following config to your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file.

***application.properties***

```
security.ignored=/**
myproject.security.enabled=false
```

**OR**

***application.yml***

```
security:
  ignored: /**

myproject:
  security:
    enabled: false
```

Comment: Is it possible to use only one property?

Comment: @wakedeer  your comment seems cryptic, could you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean that security.ignored=/**  is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

As previously multiple solutions mentioned to disable security through commenting of

> @EnableWebSecurity

annotation and other is through properties in application.properties or yml. But those properties are showing as deprecated in latest spring boot version.

So, I would like to share another approach to configure default username and password in your **application-dev.properties** or **application-dev.yml** and use them to login into swagger and etc in development environment.

```
spring.security.user.name=admin
spring.security.user.password=admin
```

So, this approach will also provides you some kind of security as well and you can share this information with your development team. You can also configure user roles as well, but its not required in development level.

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring Boot 2.7.3 using `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {})` generated an error, suggesting the `exclude` property be used in the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation.

Here is what worked for me when disabling Spring Security completely.

```
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
                ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
        })
public class GeoServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GeoServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I tried excluding only `SecurityAutoConfiguration.class`, but I got an error for no `HttpSecurity` bean defined for `ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class`.

Answer (score 1):

Latest spring 2.7.x, create two class, set DISABLE_KEYCLOAK_AUDIT_PROPERTY = 'your key' in application profile for enable/disable security:

```java
    public static final String DISABLE_KEYCLOAK_AUDIT_PROPERTY = "enable_security";
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude =
            {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
                    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class
            })
    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = DISABLE_KEYCLOAK_AUDIT_PROPERTY, havingValue = "true")
    static
    class DisableSecurityConfig {
    }

    @Configuration
    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = DISABLE_KEYCLOAK_AUDIT_PROPERTY, havingValue = "false")
    @Import({KeycloakSecurityConfig.class, KeycloakConfig.class})
    static
    class EnableSecurityConfig {
    }
```

### for example use in application.yml:

enable_security: true

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // disable CSRF, http basic, form login
                .csrf().disable() 
                .httpBasic().disable() 
                .formLogin().disable().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) 
                .and().exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines to your main app.

Remove org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class if you're not using activiti.

Similarly, remove the one for actuator if you're not using spring-boot-actuator.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
org.activiti.spring.boot.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Answer (score 0):

With Gradle and Spring boot v2.4.4, you can exclude spring security completely by adding this config in your `build.gradle`

```
configurations.all {
    exclude group:"org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-security"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With Spring 2.6.0 this helped in my case:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityDataConfiguration.class
})
```

And additional I had to remove the dependency in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Security 5.7.0-M2 `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` was deprecated. Spring Security team encourages users to move towards a component-based security configuration.

```
package com.may.security;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll(); // config to permit all requests
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() { // to delete default username and password that is printed in the log every time, you can provide here any auth manager (InMemoryAuthenticationManager, etc) as you need
        return authentication -> {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        };
    }
}
```

More examples here:

https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter

Answer (score 0):

For a reactive webflux springboot application (in my case it is not a controller application, but a scheduler application) with out any http requests, none of the application.properties examples or exclude annotations worked. The only way worked for me is by adding a filter class.

I am using springboot 2.6.5, and have the below artifacts mainly besides some kafka and db related artifacts

**pom.xml**

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
```

**application.proeprties:**

***I did not add spring.main.web-application-type=reactive***

**Filter class:**

***NOTE: I did not even added @EnableWebFluxSecurity OR @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity, but it is still works.***

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableReactiveMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurityFilter {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.authorizeExchange().pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll().and().build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationNoSecurity {

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/**");
    }
}
```

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-disable-profile

Answer (score -3):

I added below settings in application.yml and worked fine.

```
security:
    route-patterns-to-be-skipped:
      - /**/*
```

this can be converted as `security.route-paterns-to-be-skipped=/**/*` for application.properties

Comment: This property doesn't exist at all.