# disabling spring security in spring boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-java-config

I have a spring boot web app with spring security configured. I want to disable authentication for a while (until needed).

I add this to the `application.properties`:

```
security.basic.enable: false   
management.security.enabled: false
```

Here is some part of my

But I still have a basic security included : There is a default security password generated at startup and I am still getting HTTP Authentication prompt box.

My pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>fr.test.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>navigo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <!-- Inherit defaults from Spring Boot -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <jsoup.version>1.8.3</jsoup.version>
        <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>
        <postgresql.version>9.3-1103-jdbc41</postgresql.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- Add typical dependencies for a web application -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>${jsoup.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Package as an executable jar -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Add Spring repositories -->
    <!-- (you don't need this if you are using a .RELEASE version) -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

The security is configured in WebSecurityConfig.java (I have commented the annotation to disable it) :

```
//@Configuration
//@EnableWebSecurity
//@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
//@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/bus/topologie", "/home")
        // http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
        // .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')").and()
        // .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
        // .defaultSuccessUrl("/bus/topologie").loginPage("/login")
        // .permitAll().and().logout()
        // .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        // .logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll().and().rememberMe()
        // .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
        // .tokenRepository(persistentTokenRepository())
        // .tokenValiditySeconds(86400).and().csrf();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistentTokenRepository persistentTokenRepository() {
        JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl tokenRepositoryImpl = new JdbcTokenRepositoryImpl();
        tokenRepositoryImpl.setDataSource(datasource);
        return tokenRepositoryImpl;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {

        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(datasource);

        if (!userService.userExists("user")) {
            User userAdmin = new User("user", encoder.encode("password"), true);
            Set<Authorities> authorities = new HashSet<Authorities>();
            authorities.add(new Authorities(userAdmin,"ADMIN"));
            authorities.add(new Authorities(userAdmin,"CRIP"));
            authorities.add(new Authorities(userAdmin,"USER"));
            userAdmin.setAuthorities(authorities);

            userService.createUser(userAdmin);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot Security Disable security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use `security.ignored` property:

```
security.ignored=/**
```

`security.basic.enable: false` will just disable some part of the security auto-configurations but your `WebSecurityConfig` still will be registered.

> There is a default security password generated at startup

Try to `Autowired` the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`:

```
@Override
@Autowired
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { ... }
```

Comment: is security.ignored=/** to go in the securityconfig class or application.properties ?

Comment: Nice answer. Just to add, security.ignored=/** doesn't turn off CSRF, which still has to disabled

Comment: it won't work for Spring Boot 2 as disabling from `application.properties` is deprecated. Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292134/2443988

Comment: An alternative for spring boot 2, se my answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53670356/2970422

Comment: If you wanted to work with security.basic.enabled: false, see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/65939294/3888628

Answer (score 53):

Try this. Make a new class

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
}

}
```

Basically this tells Spring to allow access to every url. `@Configuration` tells spring it's a configuration class

Comment: I got it to go by adding both exclude statement for the autoconfigure.security and .permitAll() on the antMatchers.

Comment: \@EnableWebSecurity is needed in the 
    \@EnableWebSecurity
    protected static class SecurityConfiguration

Comment: You can also annotate a class like this with something like `@Profile("nosecure")` so that you can specify the profile "nosecure" until you want it turned on.

Comment: Not other solutions but this worked for me on SB v 2.0.0RELEASE. security.ignored=/** was also no required. Just this class was suffiecient

Comment: ```WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter``` - is deprecated.

Answer (score 47):

security.ignored is [deprecated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#security) since Spring Boot 2.

For me simply extend the Annotation of your Application class did the Trick:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Answer (score 18):

With this solution you can fully enable/disable the security by activating a specific profile by command line. I defined the profile in a file `application-nosecurity.yaml`

```
spring:
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Then I modified my custom `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` by adding the `@Profile("!nosecurity")` as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
@Profile("!nosecurity")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {...}
```

To fully disable the security it's enough to start the application up by specifying the **nosecurity** profile, i.e.:

```
java -jar  target/myApp.jar --spring.profiles.active=nosecurity
```

Comment: setting that exclude line in the application yml did the job for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

I think you must also remove security auto config from your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class,
    org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 11):

Since security.disable option is banned from usage there is still a way to achieve it from pure config without touching any class flies (for me it creates convenience with environments manipulation and possibility to activate it with ENV variable) if you use Boot

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
```

Answer (score 10):

For me only excluding the following classes worked:

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class}) {
  // ... 
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2022.

Answer (score 5):

just add

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)

Comment: where need to add?

Answer (score 5):

Change `WebSecurityConfig.java`: comment out everything in the `configure` method and add

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();
```

This will allow any request to hit every URL without any authentication.

Comment: `http.authorizeRequests` rather.

Comment: It's manual, but why not.

Answer (score 4):

This was the only thing that worked for me, I added the following annotation to my Application class and exclude SecurityAutoConfiguration

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;

@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        SecurityAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Comment: I did something similar, but now I was wondering which are the benefits of this solution compared to just having:  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

Answer (score 4):

You could just comment the maven dependency for a while:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
</dependencies>
```

It worked fine for me

> Disabling it from `application.properties` is deprecated for Spring Boot
>   2.0

Answer (score 2):

Use `@profile("whatever-name-profile-to-activate-if-needed")` on your security configuration class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
security.ignored=/**

security.basic.enable: false
```

NB. I need to debug to know why why exclude auto configuration did not work for me. But the profile is sot so bad as you can still re-activate it via configuration properties if needed

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following line to disable spring auto configuration in application.properties file

`spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration`

it works on spring 2.0.5 :)

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer didn't work for me.

If you have a multi configuration, adding the following to your WebSecurityConfig class worked for me (ensure that your Order(1) is lower than all of your other Order annotations in the class):

```
/* UNCOMMENT TO DISABLE SPRING SECURITY */
    /*@Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class DisableSecurityConfigurationAdapater extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        }
    }*/
```

Comment: we need  the (disable/enable° configuration programmatically done

Comment: @AhmedRebai did the solution not work for you? It worked no problem for me.