# Cannot disable security in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I want to disable spring security in my app and I set the property security.basic.enable=false in the application.yml file.

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

And I checked the /env using spring-boot-actuator and find it's loaded correctly:(at line 2)

```
[classpath:/application.yml]":{"spring.datasource.url":"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/toe?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&allowMultiQueries=true","spring.datasource.username":"root","spring.datasource.password":"******",
"security.basic.enabled":false,
"server.port":7777,"flyway.enabled":false}}
```

However,the security configuration is still work, I can't access the ones need authenticated, but I can access those are permitAll.

This is the application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("team.xuli.toe.dao")
public class ToeServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ToeServerApplication.class, args);}
}
```

This is the securityConfigutaion:

```
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http.csrf().disable();
      http.httpBasic();
      http.
             authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
             .anyRequest().authenticated();
  }
  @Autowired
  public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      System.out.println("user added in mem!");
      auth
          .inMemoryAuthentication()
              .withUser("xqf").password("123").roles("ADMIN");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I tried to set  the property security.ignored=/** and success. There's a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280181/disabling-spring-security-in-spring-boot-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a `@Configuration` with `@EnableWebSecurity` anywhere in your application it will switch off the default webapp security settings in Spring Boot.

Comment: Thanks, it has been solved. I tried to set the property security.ignored=/** and success. There's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280181/disabling-spring-security-in-spring-boot-app

Answer (score 0):

If you need security as a dependency but don't want Spring Boot to configure it for you, you can use this exclusion:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { 
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class

    })
```