# Spring Boot 2 http.httpBasic().disable(); not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I recently upgraded from Spring Boot 1.x to Spring Boot 2.0.3 and I am trying to disable basic auth with no success.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class CustomSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.httpBasic().disable();
        // the rest of my config
    }
}
```

What hidden gem am I missing to just simply turn off basic auth?
Why does turning things off in Spring need to be so difficult now?

I was reading this:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10306
and I have to agree that it should be much easier and a clearer explanation should be provided on how to turn this off.

EDIT

This link https://spring.io/blog/2017/09/15/security-changes-in-spring-boot-2-0-m4  talks about how the property was removed but doesn't say anything about how to continue to use the configuration as it exists in current application that utilize it.

Comment: I just want basic auth disabled but the context of the discussion about how unclear it is to disable anything is more of what I was getting at with the link.

Comment: This linked issue is already solved (in some way), the way to disable Spring Security with Spring Boot 2.x is documentated, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258766/spring-boot-2-0-x-disable-security-for-certain-profile. rwinch's other options are not mentioned, but still usable.

Comment: However, your code should disable HTTP basic authtentication. Maybe the problem is `super.configure(http);`. Why do you call super class?

Comment: the Spring Boot Security 2.0 migration guide says that simply adding WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and putting my config in should work but it does not.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258766/spring-boot-2-0-x-disable-security-for-certain-profile was helpful though and seems to have worked.  not sure why it didn't come up in any of my google searches.

Comment: Okay, now I'm confused. If you want to disable Spring Security completely your question is a dupe, see my link. But you wrote, that you only want to disable HTTP basic authentication, then your question is not a duplicate of the other question. Your code (at least without calling super) should work.

Comment: How do you solve your problem?

Comment: @dur the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258766/spring-boot-2-0-x-disable-security-for-certain-profile seems to have set me straight.  at least my custom security is now working and I am no longer being hassled by the basic auth login screen