# Why Spring Security application redirects to login page though we don't provide spring security configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I don't provide any Spring Security configuration and every request URL redirected to the login page. I've created a Spring Boot application using "Spring Initializr" with required Spring Security dependency.

Why it's redirecting every request to the login page? How to disable this?

I tried it removing all security configuration.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootJwtExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootJwtExampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}

public interface VehicleRepository extends JpaRepository<Vehicle, Long> {
}


@Data
@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/vehicles")
public class VehicleController {

    @Autowired
    private VehicleRepository vehicleRepository;

    @GetMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity getAll(){
        return ok(vehicleRepository.findAll());
    }
}
```

When I request http://localhost:8080/v1/vehicles
its redirecting to the login page. it supposed to request actual request.

Comment: Remove Spring Security? The only other way would be to configure it correctly rather then letting it load defaults.

Comment: @Vikas you may need to remove the security dependency

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot 2.0.x disable security for certain profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258766/spring-boot-2-0-x-disable-security-for-certain-profile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity), the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class provides the following default configuration:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .and()
        .httpBasic();
}
```

To override these defaults, write your own `WebSecurityConfig` such as:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Your own rules
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to disable temporary spring security, add the annotation    @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class}) in your spring main class

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
  public class DemoApplication
  {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
      SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
  }
  ```
- Another solution is to override the default configuration by extending the
  class

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableWebSecurity
  public class BasicConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //customize the configs
  }
  }
  ```
- Finally, if you do not need security in your project, remove the spring security dependency in the pom.xml file.