# Bypass login based on profile

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

It kind of annoying to log in to a spring boot application N times a day while testing or debugging it . is there a way this can be turned off based on the profile.

for example:  **dev** profile does not need to go  through the spring security login filter chain and is already authenticated

Comment: You can disable the  bean configuration based on profile by using @conditionalonproperty and checking the value is equal to dev or not.

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258766/spring-boot-2-0-x-disable-security-for-certain-profile