# Disable security on springboot2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

i'm trying to disable default security in Springboot 2, but i can't.

In sprinboot 1.5 i have used security.basic.enabled=false, but now it's deprecated.

I'm trying to create a configuration class that extends WebConfigurationAdapter overriding the configure method like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class StackWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends 
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().disable();
    // http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll(); // Also doesn't work.
}
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273691/spring-boot-2-0-disable-default-security

Comment: @AungMyatHein:  If you think something's a dupe, flag it as such.

Comment: it doesn't work! any of the other response

Comment: @MatteoLongo: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258766/spring-boot-2-0-x-disable-security-for-certain-profile