# Spring back end localhost requires login

Tags: spring, cordova, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to develop a cross-platform application, with Cordova in the front-end and using Spring in the back_end.
Basically, I started by the link between the database and generating the classes (models). Here's my application properties:

```
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql = true

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = updateUnable to find column with logical name: program_id

# Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager)

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

# Server
server.port=8080

endpoints.cors.allowed-origins=*
```

I wanted to try if I'm getting the list in JSON form before I go to the backend. So I made an example to get the list of operators, the class Operator is declared like that:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.rest.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

/**
 *
 * @author gate11
 */
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "db_suivi", schema = "")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Operator.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM Operator o")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Operator.findById", query = "SELECT o FROM Operator o WHERE o.id = :id")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Operator.findByOperatorFName", query = "SELECT o FROM Operator o WHERE o.operatorFName = :operatorFName")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Operator.findByOperatorLName", query = "SELECT o FROM Operator o WHERE o.operatorLName = :operatorLName")})
public class Operator implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Long id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String operatorFName;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    private String operatorLName;
    @JoinTable(name = "BadgeOperator", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "idOp", referencedColumnName = "id")}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "idBad", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<BadgePoint> badgePointList;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "operatorList", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Zone> zoneList;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "operator", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TimePass> timePassList;

    public Operator() {
    }

    public Operator(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Operator(Long id, String operatorFName, String operatorLName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.operatorFName = operatorFName;
        this.operatorLName = operatorLName;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getOperatorFName() {
        return operatorFName;
    }

    public void setOperatorFName(String operatorFName) {
        this.operatorFName = operatorFName;
    }

    public String getOperatorLName() {
        return operatorLName;
    }

    public void setOperatorLName(String operatorLName) {
        this.operatorLName = operatorLName;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<BadgePoint> getBadgePointList() {
        return badgePointList;
    }

    public void setBadgePointList(List<BadgePoint> badgePointList) {
        this.badgePointList = badgePointList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<Zone> getZoneList() {
        return zoneList;
    }

    public void setZoneList(List<Zone> zoneList) {
        this.zoneList = zoneList;
    }

    @XmlTransient
    public List<TimePass> getTimePassList() {
        return timePassList;
    }

    public void setTimePassList(List<TimePass> timePassList) {
        this.timePassList = timePassList;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Operator)) {
            return false;
        }
        Operator other = (Operator) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.rest.Operator[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

I added an interface (repository) implementing JpaRepository:

```
    /*
     * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
     * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
     * and open the template in the editor.
     */
    package com.rest.repository;

    import com.rest.model.Operator;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

        /**
         *
     * @author gate11
     */
    public interface OperatorRepository extends JpaRepository<Operator, Long>{
        @Override
        List<Operator> findAll(); 
    }

And as needed, also a controller for the class Operator:

package com.rest.rest;

import com.rest.model.Operator;
import com.rest.service.OperatorService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import static org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod.GET;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)

public class OperatorController {
    @Autowired
    private OperatorService operatorService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/operator/all")
    public List<Operator> loadAll() {
        return this.operatorService.findAll();
    }

}
```

The interface service:

```
package com.rest.service;

import com.rest.model.Operator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author gate11
 */
public interface OperatorService {
    List<Operator> findAll();
}
```

The service Implement also:

```
package com.rest.serviceImp;

import com.rest.model.Operator;
import com.rest.repository.OperatorRepository;
import com.rest.service.OperatorService;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 *
 * @author gate11
 */
@Service
public class OperatorServiceImp implements OperatorService{

    @Autowired
    private OperatorRepository operatorRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Operator> findAll() {
            List<Operator> operator = operatorRepository.findAll();
            return operator;
        }

}
```

When I launch the application, the log:

```
2018-03-05 14:34:47.427  INFO 10768 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/css/**'], Ant [pattern='/js/**'], Ant [pattern='/images/**'], Ant [pattern='/webjars/**'], Ant [pattern='/**/favicon.ico'], Ant [pattern='/error']]], []
2018-03-05 14:34:47.565  INFO 10768 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: Ant [pattern='/h2-console/**'], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@183bb809, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@593fdbbe, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@2d784ff4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@55ef8d65, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@3ba7a547, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@12e1efcb, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@57449117, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5cba96fc, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@5403d62a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4817a878, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@36126980]
2018-03-05 14:34:47.573  INFO 10768 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: OrRequestMatcher [requestMatchers=[Ant [pattern='/**']]], [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@70c855ab, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@1eef0aa6, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@537d0675, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@7d1011c1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@1b4c8eff, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@73c2d36e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@48372dcd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3cfcbfa3, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4befcfad, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4ed4729f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@dffb1e0]
2018-03-05 14:34:47.807  INFO 10768 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-03-05 14:34:47.900  INFO 10768 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-03-05 14:34:48.000  INFO 10768 --- [  restartedMain] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-03-05 14:34:48.008  INFO 10768 --- [  restartedMain] com.rest.Application                     : Started Application in 10.365 seconds (JVM running for 11.067)
2018-03-05 14:42:28.257  INFO 10768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2018-03-05 14:42:28.257  INFO 10768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2018-03-05 14:42:28.279  INFO 10768 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 21 ms
```

Then, I should go to localhost:8080/api/operator/all to get the list of operator as I used to do, but it's asking me to use a username password, I tried everything from db user (root, root) but doesn't work.
I don't even have a connexion page in the application.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HA57.png)

If you have any idea, please feel free to suggest, I'm using a Mac as you see.
Thanks.

Comment: See your console it will spit out a generated password. If spring security starter (I assume this is spring boot) it will lockdown everything by default.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe I think you're right, I tried it too 
Using default security password: c197d9cb-bb38-41ac-8840-f8dc50ca5abb
but no username generated.

Comment: I _think_ default username is `user`

Comment: Close spring security. Check the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36280413/1530849