# How to disable jhipster log-in system

Tags: authentication, jhipster

I'll put this as simple as I can.

I wanna disable any logins on my jhipster application.
I want the user to be able to use the page right after he/she connects to my page.

Thank you in advance to anyone willing to help

Comment: Please edit your question to list options you chose like frontend framework, authentication type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36280181/disabling-spring-security-in-spring-boot-app might help.