# BCrypt + Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, bcrypt

I have this controller to create users:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> insert(@Valid @RequestBody UserDTO userDTO,
        UriComponentsBuilder uriInfo) {

    User user = UserDTO.getEntity(userDTO);
    final Long id = service.insert(user);

    final URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(id).toUri();

    return ResponseEntity.created(location).build();

}
```

And this service expect a JSON like this:

```
{
    "profile": "ROLE_ADMIN",
    "name": "Administrador",
    "phone": "71234567890",
    "username": "admin",
    "email": "admin@mail.com",
    "password": "123456"
}
```

I have a service that picks up this user and changes the password to an encrypted one:

```
public Long insert(User user) {
        user.setPassword(PasswordUtils.generateBCrypt(user.getPassword()));
        repository.save(user);
        return user.getId();
    }
```

And the PasswordUtils.class have the code below:

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

public class PasswordUtils {

    public static String generateBCrypt(String password) {

        if (password == null) {
            return password;
        }

        BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return encoder.encode(password);

    }

}
```

In my **pom.xml** I commented the **spring-boot-starter-security** dependency, because when I do not comment the same it will ask me for username and password to make the request. When I call the REST service the error: **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException error occurs: org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder**.

How to use BCrypt without my service ask for the credentials?

**EDIT**

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.heart</groupId>
    <artifactId>echocardiogram</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>echocardiogram</name>
    <description>Echocardiogram Management System</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot Security Disable security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security)

Comment: FWIW, there's no reason at all to create a new encoder every time. Make it a constant or inject a common instance.

Comment: @chrylis, even with injection the error persists.

Comment: I am not  very sure about this approach. Try to create bean for `BCryptPasswordEncoder`  and do auto-wiring for the same. **Maybe bad idea**