# Disable security in Activiti 7

Tags: spring, spring-boot, activiti

I am using activiti 7, I want to disable activiti security. I tried to override WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter config method, but it is not working

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception
    {
        security.httpBasic().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working because.... ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot Security Disable security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security)

Answer (score 0):

Activiti Core (7) relies on Spring Security to do user & roles checks.
Can you please clarify why do you want to disable security? It might be worth understanding what your use case is to make sure that we can cover it it correctly. 
Please create an issue in GitHub.com/activiti/activiti/issues so we can have a more in detail conversation. 
In general we found that the @EnableWebSecurity it is quite strong annotation and quite difficult to deal with. Can you also state which version are you using? We just released Activiti Core and Cloud SR1 which we recommend to try out -> https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.activiti.dependencies/activiti-dependencies/7.0.0.SR1/pom

Comment: Our application is for Internal purpose and we dont need to add any security layer for this, because of that i was looking for some way to disable it. Anyway i have created a dummy role and user to access it and it is working fine.

Comment: Great to know.. for internal usage that is the way to go! Thanks for the feedback