# Spring boot 1.5 disable oauth2 security

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

How can I disable the oauth2 security filtering in my Spring boot app, or skip the security checks, 
I just want to hit the **GET** and **POST** end points in the Spring boot **@RestController** directly without going through the security filtering.

I'm using below **configurations**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      access-token-validity-seconds: 3600
  tokenExtractor:
    type: header
```

**pom.xml dependencies**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Spring version**

```
<spring.version>4.3.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.boot.version>1.5.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
```

Comment: Why are you adding spring-security if you want to ignore it?

Comment: There is no mandate to add security in spring if you don't want it

Comment: i want to skip security checks for testing purposes of other internal GET, POST urls

Comment: Possible duplicate of this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security question.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to remove the entire Spring Security, you can add ignore configuration for all you urls in your Spring Configuration bean:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers(
            "/**");
}
```

Comment: thanks, i found the deny rule in the class, **@Configuration**
public class ResourceAccessConfiguration **extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter** {@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {List<RequestMatcher> matchers = Arrays.stream(new String[]{"/**/payment/**"}).map(AntPathRequestMatcher::new).collect(Collectors.toList()); **http.authorizeRequests().requestMatchers(new OrRequestMatcher(matchers)).denyAll();**}}

Answer (score 1):

3 ways

**A.** I was able to achive bypassing spring boot security filtering while keeping the @EnableResourceServer in the @SpringBootApplication Application class

1.**permitall** for **anonymous** in the ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter override

```
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ResourceAccessConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().anonymous();<< this will allow any resource endpoint access when the HTTP request Authorization header not available
        //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();<< also can
    }
}
```

spring boot application initializer

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableResourceServer << keep this
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

2.remove the authorization header(remove OAuth 2.0 Access Token from the HTTP request)

[image]

**B.** security filtering could also be disabled for endpoints by **removing @EnableResourceServer** and set the parameter in application.yml as below.
when removed @EnableResourceServer the spring security config will fall back to default which is `org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

1.application.yml, security.ignored property

```
security:
  ignored: /**
```

2.spring boot application initializer

```
@SpringBootApplication
//@EnableResourceServer << remove this
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

3.remove the authorization header same as above

**C.** security filtering could also be disabled for endpoints by removing @EnableResourceServer and adding a config class extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

1.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

2.//@EnableResourceServer commented same as above

3.remove the authorization header same as above