# How to load beans into test context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have the REST service that I need to testing. That service has a spring security authentication and I need to turn off it in my tests or mock. I decided to mock it because I couldn't turn off it. I write `@TestConfiguration` for that but now my context not load:

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {
}

@WebMvcTest(controller = MyController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public MyControllerTest {
    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
    }
}
```

and in my main source, I have some config class that load some other beans and it class did not load in my test and I have an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

What I do wrong? Can anyone help me? I using `SpringBoot 2.2.0` and in that version `@WebMvcTest(secure = false)` not working because of `secure` property doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Are you using XML based configuration of annotation?

Comment: @Lakshman no, I using annotation-based configuration

Comment: It can be done, try this 
Create 1 test-applicatio.properties in src\test\resource add below properties to skip security 
security.basic.enabled=false
management.security.enabled=false       
and you can use @ContextConfiguration(locations ={}) to import property file

Comment: Why couldn't you turn security off using yaml/properties file? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security

Comment: @Ermintar I don't use basic HTTP authentication, I use a custom authentication provider and this approach not works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try overriding the security configuration in your test class:

```
@WebMvcTest(controller = MyController.class)
public MyControllerTest {

    @Configuration
    public class MyTestsSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            //...
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            //...
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void simpleTest() {
    }
}
```

Also have a look at this here: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/testing/springboot-test-configuration/