# status:401 unauthorized in postman

Tags: spring-boot, postman

Iam working in springboot application and iam trying to save the data in database, code is executing properly and not getting any error during execution but when iam trying to post the url in postman iam getting status: 401 unauthorized

any quick suggestion

console

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)
2020-12-08 17:34:07.094  INFO 7236 --- [           main] c.regestration.RegestrationApplication   : Starting RegestrationApplication on Darshan with PID 7236 (C:\Users\admin\Desktop\regestration\target\classes started by admin in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\regestration)
2020-12-08 17:34:07.111  INFO 7236 --- [           main] c.regestration.RegestrationApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-12-08 17:34:08.584  INFO 7236 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
2020-12-08 17:34:08.803  INFO 7236 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 202ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-12-08 17:34:10.751  INFO 7236 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8085 (http)
2020-12-08 17:34:10.788  INFO 7236 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-12-08 17:34:10.788  INFO 7236 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.38]
2020-12-08 17:34:11.158  INFO 7236 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-12-08 17:34:11.158  INFO 7236 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3827 ms
2020-12-08 17:34:11.617  INFO 7236 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-12-08 17:34:11.815  INFO 7236 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-12-08 17:34:11.935  WARN 7236 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-12-08 17:34:12.006  INFO 7236 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final
2020-12-08 17:34:13.075  INFO 7236 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-12-08 17:34:13.554  INFO 7236 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-12-08 17:34:14.050  INFO 7236 --- [           main] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 
Using generated security password: 7406d0eb-72dc-4ce4-a8cc-220d3c523098
2020-12-08 17:34:14.273  INFO 7236 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@574cd322, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@55e2fe3c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@64f1fd08, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7187bac9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@5c8e67b9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1174a305, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@43e1692f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@45c2e0a6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@1f3165e7, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@12c60152, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@692e028d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@119c745c, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@282ffbf5, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@6c15e8c7, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3a08078c]
2020-12-08 17:34:14.874  INFO 7236 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8085 (http) with context path ''
2020-12-08 17:34:14.884  INFO 7236 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-12-08 17:34:14.889  INFO 7236 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-12-08 17:34:14.948  INFO 7236 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2020-12-08 17:34:18.480  INFO 7236 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-12-08 17:34:18.495  INFO 7236 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-12-08 17:34:18.881  INFO 7236 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-12-08 17:34:18.890  INFO 7236 --- [           main] c.regestration.RegestrationApplication   : Started RegestrationApplication in 13.562 seconds (JVM running for 19.799)
2020-12-08 17:34:42.030  INFO 7236 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-12-08 17:34:42.031  INFO 7236 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-12-08 17:34:42.050  INFO 7236 --- [nio-8085-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 19 ms
```

controller

```
package com.regestration.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.regestration.repository.Repository;
import com.regestration.user.User;

@RestController
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    Repository repo;
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveReg", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public HashMap<String, Object>saveRegestration(@RequestBody User user){
        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        repo.save(user);
        map.put("code", "200");
        map.put("code", "saved");
        return map;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myshadi?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.datasource.password= root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
server.port=8085
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring is activating by default the security.
See line : Using generated security password: 7406d0eb-72dc-4ce4-a8cc-220d3c523098.

You have to inactivate the security if you don't need it : [Spring boot Security Disable security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security)