# When applying the annotation, it throws an error (@SpringBootApplication)

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-mvc, spring-security

such a question. When adding the annotation @SpringBootApplication(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class}) Gives an error when building Name expected The IDE writes like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRgJW.png)

What could be the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894010/spring-boot-security-disable-security

Comment: Please add code as code and not as a link to an image. If the image is import at least include it properly into your question so that readers don't have to click additional links to get a full overview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by tags that you are using kotlin and it has slightly different syntax actually.

Change

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
```

To

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude=[SecurityAutoConfiguration::class])
```

Comment: Updated the answer with full line of code, use it and the issue gets resolved