# How am I supposed to access my endpoints in a no-config WebFlux Security application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Suppose, this is my app. It has no explicit config and only one controller with one endpoint. Very simple

```java
package com.example.securitymre.controller;

import com.example.securitymre.data.Hello;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public Hello getHello() {
        return new Hello();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.securitymre.data;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class Hello {
    private String message = "Hello!";

    public Hello(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.securitymre;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SecurityMreApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecurityMreApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I try to hit `GET /hello`, I receive a 401 error which is weird since I haven't configured any security. However, I have Spring Security in my classpath

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>security-mre</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>security-mre</name>
    <description>security-mre</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Suppose, due to that dependency, there's some autoconfiguration that requires each request to be authenticated. But what are my requests authenticated against? I haven't configured any `UserDetailsService` that queries a database or something

Is there any way I can interact with a Spring Boot Security application with **no explicit configuration** and **actually visit my endpoints**? Or is it in practical terms inaccessible unless I explicitly write some configuration?

Comment: What do you mean by "config-less" ? The configuration is driven by convention, isnt'it?

Comment: @RomanC it means with no explicit config at all

Comment: this is the (relevant) spring-boot autoconfig: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/reactive/ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.java , https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/security/reactive/ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.java

Comment: (if you don't provide `user.name|password` config, default name will be "user" and password will be generated and logged (lvl=info) to console ..this is not recommended but ready for "prod"!) ... https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/SecurityProperties.java

Comment: @xerx593 I know, it's a self-answered question

Comment: S. Here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23894010/592355 ...there is no valid reason to have spring-security as dependency not using it.

Comment: This Q&A is being discussed [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/428165/how-can-we-discipline-unscrupulous-mods).

Answer (score -5, accepted):

***Note.** This answer is intended not only to answer the question but also to give a better understanding of Spring Security's internals. If you're only interested in the answer itself, skip to the bold part*

Yes, there are a few ways you can access your endpoint

First, you need to understand what Spring Security is. Essentially, it's an extension to Spring Web that makes it easier to add security filters to your application. All those fluent methods of `(Server)HttpSecurity` are in the end simply mapped to a bunch of filters that are, by default, applied on each request. When it comes to authentication, the central role is played by Spring's `AuthenticationWebFilter`. Here's what it does

1. It extracts an `Authentication` from the exchange with the help of an `AuthenticationConverter`. Its basic implementation, `ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter`, takes the request's `Authorization` header, which it expects to be in the format of `basic <Base64-encoded string>`, discards the "basic" prefix, decodes the encoded claims, and splits the resulting string by a colon (`:`). What's on the left side of it is assumed to be a username, what's on the right side of it is assumed to be a password

```java
// AuthenticationWebFilter's converter is initialized to ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter in-line. You can change it by calling a setter, but it never happens when there's no explicit config

public class AuthenticationWebFilter implements WebFilter {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(AuthenticationWebFilter.class);

    private final ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver<ServerWebExchange> authenticationManagerResolver;

    private ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler = new WebFilterChainServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler();

    private ServerAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter = new ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter();
```

```java
// ServerHttpBasicAuthenticationConverter

    public Mono<Authentication> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        ServerHttpRequest request = exchange.getRequest();
        String authorization = request.getHeaders().getFirst(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
        if (!StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(authorization, "basic ")) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        String credentials = (authorization.length() <= BASIC.length()) ? "" : authorization.substring(BASIC.length());
        String decoded = new String(base64Decode(credentials), this.credentialsCharset);
        String[] parts = decoded.split(":", 2);
        if (parts.length != 2) {
            return Mono.empty();
        }
        return Mono.just(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(parts[0], parts[1]));
    }

    private byte[] base64Decode(String value) {
        try {
            return Base64.getDecoder().decode(value);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return new byte[0];
        }
    }
```

2. Then it delegates the actual authentication to its `AuthenticationManager`. `AuthenticationManager` is an interface with one method, `authenticate()`, which takes an `Authentication` and returns an `Authentication`. It has to, at the very least, check the credentials (a password, typically) and then, if they are valid, return an authenticated `Authentication` (one that returns `true` on `isAuthenticated()` calls). That `Authentication` is then put in a `SecurityContext` thus making the *request itself* authenticated

```java
// AuthenticationWebFilter

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
        return this.requiresAuthenticationMatcher.matches(exchange)
            .filter((matchResult) -> matchResult.isMatch())
            // the filter tells its AuthenticationConverter to extract a token from the exchange...
            .flatMap((matchResult) -> this.authenticationConverter.convert(exchange))
            .switchIfEmpty(chain.filter(exchange).then(Mono.empty()))
            // ...and then tells its AuthenticationConverter to check the claims
            .flatMap((token) -> authenticate(exchange, chain, token))
            .onErrorResume(AuthenticationException.class, (ex) -> this.authenticationFailureHandler
                .onAuthenticationFailure(new WebFilterExchange(exchange, chain), ex));
    }

    private Mono<Void> authenticate(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain, Authentication token) {
        return this.authenticationManagerResolver.resolve(exchange)
            // here's the key part
            .flatMap((authenticationManager) -> authenticationManager.authenticate(token))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono
                .defer(() -> Mono.error(new IllegalStateException("No provider found for " + token.getClass()))))
            .flatMap(
                    (authentication) -> onAuthenticationSuccess(authentication, new WebFilterExchange(exchange, chain)))
            .doOnError(AuthenticationException.class,
                    (ex) -> logger.debug(LogMessage.format("Authentication failed: %s", ex.getMessage())));
    }
```

You didn't explicitly register an `AuthenticationManager`, but Spring Security created one for you. Here it is. It's from `ServerHttpSecurityConfiguration` (which also autoconfigured your overall `ServerHttpSecurity`)

```java
    private ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        if (this.authenticationManager != null) {
            return this.authenticationManager;
        }
        if (this.reactiveUserDetailsService != null) {
            UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager manager = new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(
                    this.reactiveUserDetailsService);
            if (this.passwordEncoder != null) {
                manager.setPasswordEncoder(this.passwordEncoder);
            }
            manager.setUserDetailsPasswordService(this.userDetailsPasswordService);
            if (!this.observationRegistry.isNoop()) {
                return new ObservationReactiveAuthenticationManager(this.observationRegistry, manager);
            }
            return manager;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

As shown in the snippet above, it creates an `AuthenticationManager` subtype called `UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager` from an *injected* `ReactiveUserDetailsService` instance. `UserDetailsService` (reactive or not) is a simple interface that retrieves a user (or rather, a `UserDetails` instance) by username. `UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager` uses it to retrieve matching `UserDetails` and then compares the presented password with the one of the `UserDetails` object. For example, if my claims are "john_dow:12345", the `AuthenticationManager` will call `userDetailsService.findByUsername("john_dow")`, then the `UserDetailsService` will, if it can, return *some* John Dow (a `UserDetails` with username `john_dow`), and finally the `AuthenticationManager` will compare my "12345" with `johnDoeUserDetails.getPassword()`. It will do it, again, indirectly by calling a boolean method `passwordEncoder.matches("12345", johnDoeUserDetails.getPassword())`. In a simple scenario, such as the one we have, the `PasswordEncoder` would do no encoding or decoding at all and basically just call `equals()` between the two arguments. In a more realistic scenario, the second argument would be an encoded password, e.g. using the Bcrypt algorithm

Anyway, once the claims are verified, the `AuthenticationManager` would create an authenticated `Authentication` like so. `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` is a subtype of `Authentication`. Notice it populates the authorities (roles) too

```java
// AbstractUserDetailsReactiveAuthenticationManager

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken createUsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(userDetails, userDetails.getPassword(),
                userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }
```

Now, you may be wondering, "Where did it find that `UserDetailsService` to *inject* if I didn't write it too?" Spring Security, again, created one for you. It's declared in another configuration class, namely `ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration`. By the way, notice the `@ConditionalOnClass` and `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotations. This is the origin of all that. You *had* a `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` class in your classpath (since you had a Spring Security dependency), but you *didn't* declare any of the listed beans explicitly, that's why this whole autoconfiguration kicked in in the first place!

```java
@AutoConfiguration(before = ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration.class, after = RSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnClass({ ReactiveAuthenticationManager.class })
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(
        value = { ReactiveAuthenticationManager.class, ReactiveUserDetailsService.class,
                ReactiveAuthenticationManagerResolver.class },
        type = { "org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.ReactiveJwtDecoder" })
@Conditional({ ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.RSocketEnabledOrReactiveWebApplication.class,
        ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.MissingAlternativeOrUserPropertiesConfigured.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SecurityProperties.class)
public class ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration {

    private static final String NOOP_PASSWORD_PREFIX = "{noop}";

    private static final Pattern PASSWORD_ALGORITHM_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^\\{.+}.*$");

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration.class);

    @Bean
    public MapReactiveUserDetailsService reactiveUserDetailsService(SecurityProperties properties,
            ObjectProvider<PasswordEncoder> passwordEncoder) {
        SecurityProperties.User user = properties.getUser();
        UserDetails userDetails = getUserDetails(user, getOrDeducePassword(user, passwordEncoder.getIfAvailable()));
        return new MapReactiveUserDetailsService(userDetails);
    }

    private UserDetails getUserDetails(SecurityProperties.User user, String password) {
        List<String> roles = user.getRoles();
        return User.withUsername(user.getName()).password(password).roles(StringUtils.toStringArray(roles)).build();
    }

    private String getOrDeducePassword(SecurityProperties.User user, PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        String password = user.getPassword();
        if (user.isPasswordGenerated()) {
            logger.info(String.format("%n%nUsing generated security password: %s%n", user.getPassword()));
        }
        if (encoder != null || PASSWORD_ALGORITHM_PATTERN.matcher(password).matches()) {
            return password;
        }
        return NOOP_PASSWORD_PREFIX + password;
    }
```

Notice what the code above does. It injects a `SecurityProperties` which has *some* nested user, then uses it as a template to create a brand new `User` which is a subtype of `UserDetails`. Let's check out the `SecurityProperties` class

```java
/**
 * Configuration properties for Spring Security.
 *
 * @author Dave Syer
 * @author Andy Wilkinson
 * @author Madhura Bhave
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.security")
public class SecurityProperties {

    /**
     * Order applied to the {@code SecurityFilterChain} that is used to configure basic
     * authentication for application endpoints. Create your own
     * {@code SecurityFilterChain} if you want to add your own authentication for all or
     * some of those endpoints.
     */
    public static final int BASIC_AUTH_ORDER = Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 5;

    /**
     * Order applied to the {@code WebSecurityCustomizer} that ignores standard static
     * resource paths.
     */
    public static final int IGNORED_ORDER = Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;

    /**
     * Default order of Spring Security's Filter in the servlet container (i.e. amongst
     * other filters registered with the container). There is no connection between this
     * and the {@code @Order} on a {@code SecurityFilterChain}.
     */
    public static final int DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER = OrderedFilter.REQUEST_WRAPPER_FILTER_MAX_ORDER - 100;

    private final Filter filter = new Filter();

    private final User user = new User();

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return this.filter;
    }

    public static class Filter {

        /**
         * Security filter chain order for Servlet-based web applications.
         */
        private int order = DEFAULT_FILTER_ORDER;

        /**
         * Security filter chain dispatcher types for Servlet-based web applications.
         */
        private Set<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class);

        public int getOrder() {
            return this.order;
        }

        public void setOrder(int order) {
            this.order = order;
        }

        public Set<DispatcherType> getDispatcherTypes() {
            return this.dispatcherTypes;
        }

        public void setDispatcherTypes(Set<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes) {
            this.dispatcherTypes = dispatcherTypes;
        }

    }

    public static class User {

        /**
         * Default user name.
         */
        private String name = "user";

        /**
         * Password for the default user name.
         */
        private String password = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        /**
         * Granted roles for the default user name.
         */
        private List<String> roles = new ArrayList<>();

        private boolean passwordGenerated = true;

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return this.password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            if (!StringUtils.hasLength(password)) {
                return;
            }
            this.passwordGenerated = false;
            this.password = password;
        }

        public List<String> getRoles() {
            return this.roles;
        }

        public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
            this.roles = new ArrayList<>(roles);
        }

        public boolean isPasswordGenerated() {
            return this.passwordGenerated;
        }

    }

}
```

So what we see is that the default user has a username "user" and a password which is a randomly generated UUID. Unless it's reset (by calling `setPassword()`), it keeps that value and *also* keeps a `passwordGenerated` flag which is accessible via `isPasswordGenerated()`. Let's get back to `ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration`

```java
        if (user.isPasswordGenerated()) {
            logger.info(String.format("%n%nUsing generated security password: %s%n", user.getPassword()));
        }
```

It appears, **if we keep our generated password, we should be able to see it in our cosole output!** Let's examine it

```
INFO 9080 --- [           main] ctiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: 82963d45-55ed-40ff-bc6c-bddef52c535a
```

Booyah! Now, we got all the information we need

1. We have a username
2. We have a password
3. We know the scheme (`basic`) and the algorithm (Base64)

All we have to do is to generate a request with an `Authorization` header that has this value: `basic <base64endcoded(user:<our random UUID>)>`. There are free online Base64 tools that you can use. I liked [this one](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/base64_encode.html). Note that you'll have a different UUID each time so you should check your console instead of pasting my UUID

[image]

[image]

*(The screenshot is from [IntelliJ's HTTP client](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#creating-http-request-files). You may use Postman or the good-old curls. Any client that lets you specify a header)*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 20
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
set-cookie: SESSION=; Max-Age=0; Expires=Sat, 17 Feb 2024 10:16:25 GMT; Path=/; HTTPOnly; SameSite=Lax

{
  "message": "Hello!"
}
```

You may have noticed that `SecurityProperties` is `@ConfigurationProperties`. It means you can easily override those default values in your properties file. You won't see that log message anymore since you're going to have you own, non-generated password

```yaml
# application.yml

spring:
  security:
    user:
      name: mickey_m
      password: pass
```

[image]

[image]

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 20
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer

{
  "message": "Hello!"
}
```

You can also make a GET request to `/login`, copy a CSRF token from the HTML, make a POST request with username, password, and the CSRF token in the request body to the same path

```
POST http://localhost:8080/login
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=mickey_m&password=pass&_csrf=MiyRbaso7IVlFnV8YstELfLORnHsvsg0JPW-qoGSqkri3WD7ChiiXZxO2rxILxFIW-ZwSJaoaxDVhv0ZRsLaz7WnnijX6VTP
```

receive a 404 (since you don't have a mapping for `/` to which a request is redirected by default), then copy the session id from the response's cookie, and hit `/hello` with that key-value pair in your `Cookie` header. You'll get the same response

```
GET http://localhost:8080/hello
Cookie: SESSION=48d946ab-b9b9-4d93-99c5-eb484a21dbbe
```

But I won't describe that method in detail since the answer is already quite long (besides, it's rather twisted)